# Facebook Graph API Events Batching

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a situation where I need to write a tool that will allow users to retrieve the events for a large number of Facebook pages (around 500 currently, but that number may fluctuate.)

Up until this point, I have been operating under the assumption that Facebook would allow us to batch up requests for events and process them, but I'm no longer sure.  Requests directly to retrieve a page's events such as: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/1419989008240078/events work beautifully, but the moment I try to batch up those requests with something like this:

```
curl \
-F 'access_token=whoops' \
-F 'batch=[{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"587297284709320/events"},{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"1407629216134445/events"}]' \
https://graph.facebook.com > ~/Desktop/tmp.txt
```

I get output like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26051227/tmp.txt), but doing something as simple as removing the events edge:

```
curl \
-F 'access_token=whoops' \
-F 'batch=[{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"587297284709320"},{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"1407629216134445"}]' \
https://graph.facebook.com > ~/Desktop/tmp.txt
```

correctly returns page data.

I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation that would suggest what I want to do is impossible, but I'm also at a loss to figure out how I should change my requests!

Following the suggestions below, I've started trying to get other methods of batching up requests to work, and it appears that there is some kind of deeper bug, as

```
curl "https://graph.facebook.com/events?ids=587297284709320&access_token=token" > ~/desktop/tmp.txt
```

also fails, but if I use the same access token in the graph API explorer, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Smells like a Facebook bug for me... Your code looks correct to me, and it's not understandable why there's something returned for page_ids, but not for the edges...

Nevertheless, you can use

```
/v2.4/?ids=587297284709320,1407629216134445&fields=events
```

Please note that if you're using Graph API v2.4, you have to specify each field you want to have returned from the Graph API, such as

```
/v2.4/?ids=587297284709320,1407629216134445&fields=events{id,name,description,place}
```

Comment: So that's a useful start and it appears to work in the graph explorer, but I can't get it to respond over the API.  Running

curl "https://graph.facebook.com/events?ids=587297284709320&access_token=token" > ~/desktop/tmp.txt

successfully completes, but fails.

Comment: You'll need to add the version prefix. Updated my answer.